# When is the change reflected on Model in Angular2 select

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a select field like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters; let idx = index">
  <select [id]="'name' + idx" [(ngModel)]="filter.name" (change)="changeFilter(idx, $event)">
    <option val="a">A</option>
    <option val="b">B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My `change()` function on the component doesn't detect the change instantly. Simplified:

```
@Component()
export class Filters {

  public filters = [{name: "a"}, {name: "b"}, {name: "a"}];

  public change(idx: number, $event: Event) {

    console.log(this.filters[idx].name === $event.target.name); // false here
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log(this.filters[idx].name === $event.target.name); // Now it's true

    }, 10);
  }
}
```

Now, if I change between the options, the change() function needs some time - usually less then 3 milliseconds on that `setTimeout`, but sometimes more.

Now, I am sure this is not the best way to detect the change, and I'll find out how to do it properly, but I'm curious as to how to determine when is the change reflected on my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` doesn't support binding to variables created by `ngFor`.

Use instead

```
[(ngModel)]="filters[idx].name"
```

You could also try

```
(ngModelChange)="changeFilter(idx, $event)"
```

`ngModelChange` is probably emitted after the value was changed while for `(change)` it depends on the browser what event and event handler is processed first (AFAIR `ngModel` uses `input`)

Comment: `ngModelChange` works, and I'll see about moving the whole thing to the full model when I get the time (right now filters isn't even the top-level model, it's a prop on another object.)